# Where are magento attributes located at in database?

Tags: php, database, magento, attributes, magento-1.7

Recently i have added a text attribute to all my attribute sets. My goal is to make this text attribute limited to 80 characters including spaces. The problem is that i can figure out where the attributes are located at in the database.

I have tried searching the magento website, but i have yet to find any information on where the attributes are found in the database.

Comment: You need to visit http://www.magereverse.com/ It gives you the table structure. As this is EAV, you will need to figure which of five tables it is stored in (text, varchar, date, decimal, int). Since it's text, that's probably catalog_product_entity_varchar. Then you have to work out what the attribute ID is.

Answer (score 0):

magento attribute located at `eav_attribute` table and its text are located in column `attribute_code`